# Roblox Lua - Gamepass Prompt Script not Executing

Tags: lua, roblox

I am making a game. I am trying to make a script that will prompt the player to buy a gamepass when they click a button on a SurfaceGUI. However, the function isn't executing, and I don't know why.

If it helps, it is in a LocalScript.

```
script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    local mps = game:GetService("MarketplaceService")
    local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
    print("vars")
    mps:PromptGamePassPurchase(player, 10772382)
    print("prompt")
end)
```

Comment: Is this LocalScript located somewhere in the Workspace? I'm assuming that since it's a child of a SurfaceGui, that it's located somewhere in the Workspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that this is a LocalScript, and LocalScripts only execute from a few locations. According to [the docs](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/LocalScript) :

> A LocalScript will only run Lua code if it is a descendant of one of the following objects:
>
> - A Player’s Backpack, such as a child of a Tool
> - A Player’s character model
> - A Player’s PlayerGui
> - A Player’s PlayerScripts.
> - The ReplicatedFirst service

So to fix your issue, convert this `LocalScript` to a `Script`, and listen for a player to join to get access to the player object.

```
local mps = game:GetService("MarketplaceService")
local ps = game:GetService("Players")

ps.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
        print("vars")
        mps:PromptGamePassPurchase(player, 10772382)
        print("prompt")
    end)
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why your current script is not working however, here is a script I use that works well(just change the ID value to your id
local id = 6604880

```
script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    game:GetService("MarketplaceService"):PromptGamePassPurchase(game.Players.LocalPlayer,id)
end)
```

Comment: The issue is that the script isn't executing at all, not that the id isn't correct. The code you have shared is functionally equivalent to the problematic code.

Comment: Kylaaa your wrong I have local scripts executing the code he his having a problem with and it works so. :/

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean to imply that this code doesn't work, only that it does not work where they have placed the code in their game, which is likely somewhere in the Workspace. If you have this code somewhere in your PlayerGui, I fully expect that it works. But considering that your code is exactly the same as theirs, this isn't the right solution.